# Quickly draw custom format image on screen

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing own image format for my game and other applications and I want to make image viewer of those images. The problem is, that when I always try to render bigger image (1920x1080), it takes atleast 10 seconds and then application stops responding for few seconds and everything disappears.

```
class Renderer{
    //...
    inline void GetRGB(unsigned int color,unsigned char &r,unsigned char &g,unsigned char &b){
        r=((color>>16)&0xff); g=((color>>8)&0xff); b=((color)&0xff);
    }
    inline bool IsValidPos(unsigned int x,unsigned int y){
        if((x>=0&&x<width)&&(y>=0&&y<height))return true;
        else return false;
    }
    inline void GetPoint(unsigned int x,unsigned int y,unsigned int &color){
        if(IsValidPos(x,y))
            color=photostream[y*height+x];
    }
    void DrawPoint(unsigned int& x,unsigned int& y){
        unsigned char r,g,b;
        unsigned int col;
        GetPoint(x,y,col);
        //GetRGB(col,r,g,b);
        SetPixel(hDC,x,y,col);
    }
};
void RenderSHMP(ImageSHMP<unsigned int>& img,Renderer *renderer){
    ImageSHMP<unsigned int> tmpImg(img.GetX(),img.GetY()); //create new image, this one will be shown
    for(unsigned int x=0;x<tmpImg.GetX();x++)
        for(unsigned int y=0;y<tmpImg.GetY();y++)
            tmpImg.SetPoint(x,y,img.GetPoint(x,y)); //copy all data
    if(img.GetX()>WIDTH||img.GetY()>HEIGHT){ //resize image if it is bigger than window resolution
        double scale=1.0;
        scale=static_cast<double>(WIDTH)/static_cast<double>(img.GetX());
        tmpImg.Scale(scale);
    }
    //code above takes max. 0,2 seconds to execute
    unsigned int col=0;
    for(unsigned int x=0;x<tmpImg.GetX();x++)
        for(unsigned int y=0;y<tmpImg.GetY();y++){
            col=tmpImg.GetPoint(x,y);
            renderer->SetPoint(x,y,col);    //sets color in memory for later use
            renderer->DrawPoint(x,y);
        }
}
```

ImageSHMP contains simple buffer of type T which is equal to width*height.
All data are saved in this buffer, so for example point [20,30] is located at [30*height+20]. 
How do I make it draw faster, so window won't be in "Not responding" state?
I mean as fast as simple Windows Image Viewer does it.

---

Final code:

```
void RenderSHMP(ImageSHMP<unsigned int>& img,Renderer *renderer){
    ImageSHMP<unsigned int> tmpImg(img.GetX(),img.GetY());
    for(unsigned int x=0;x<tmpImg.GetX();x++)
        for(unsigned int y=0;y<tmpImg.GetY();y++)
            tmpImg.SetPoint(x,y,img.GetPoint(x,y));
    if(img.GetX()>WIDTH||img.GetY()>HEIGHT){
        double scale=1.0;
        scale=static_cast<double>(WIDTH)/static_cast<double>(img.GetX());
        tmpImg.Scale(scale);
    }
    int w=tmpImg.GetX(),h=tmpImg.GetY();
    unsigned char r=0,g=0,b=0;
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    HBITMAP hbm;
    unsigned char *bytes=new unsigned char[w*h*3];
    HDC hdc;
    renderer->GetHDC(hdc);
    unsigned int ctr=0;
    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    hbm = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void **)&bytes, NULL, 0);
    HDC compatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap  (hdc, w, h);
    for(int y=int(h)-1;y>=0;--y){
        for(int x=0;x<int(w);++x){
            renderer->GetRGB(tmpImg.GetPoint(x,y),r,g,b);
            bytes[ctr++]=b;
            bytes[ctr++]=g;
            bytes[ctr++]=r;
        }
    }
    SetDIBits (hdc, hbmp, 0, h, bytes,&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    hbmp=(HBITMAP)SelectObject (compatibleDC, hbmp);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, compatibleDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(compatibleDC, hbmp));
    DeleteDC(compatibleDC);
    delete [] bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling SetPixel 2M times will take a bit of time. I think you'd be better of resizing the image into a bitmap, and then drawing that to the screen. Use for example [`CreateDIBSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then populate that via the `ppvBits`, and use BitBlit() to draw to the screen itself.

Answer (score 1):

> simple Windows Image Viewer does it.

Image viewers do not draw images pixel-by-pixel. You need to draw entire image in one system call. For that you'll need to unpack image into some representation operating system can draw, then draw decompressed image onto screen. In one call.

On windows platform you can use [SetDIBitsToDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [StretchDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Those function allow you to draw pixels onto windows from in-memory arrays as long as you fill [BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) correctly.